What's the essentially equivalent network in digital circuit?
The following is a snippet from DSP Integrated Circuits (Academic Press Series in Engineering)  by Lars Wanhammar.
Essentially equivalent network in digital circuit.
Theorem 6.3 states:

If an arbitrary, nonlinear, time-varying discrete time network, \$N_n\$, has delay elements in series with all inputs (outputs), then all the delays can be moved to the outputs (inputs) and the properties of \$N_n\$ shifted, according to Figure 6.31, without changing the input-output behavior of the composite system. \$N_n\$ and \$N_{n+1}\$ denote the properties of the network with reference to samples \$n\$ and \$n+1\$, respectively.


What's the equivalent network for the following figure?



The following is what I think:
The half delay from first lattice will be moved to the second lattice. And two half delays will combine into one full delay.


(I think what the author thinks to be somewhat equivalent is in Figure 6.33.)

@greybeard I knew author thinks to be somewhat equivalent is in Figure 6.33. But where am I wrong in my thinking?

I think Figure 6.33 is not equivalent if each box was identical to the same position in 6.32.
And I think the '99 edition contains an error there in "the non-dashed T-box" on the lower-right: the label/delay should be \$T\$, not \$T/2\$.
So to be equivalent, at least one of those symmetric two-port adaptors (Figure 4.31) would need to be adapted to the structural change.
(A lattice would be a regular/periodic arrangement of elements in at least one dimension, cf Figure 4.45 showing a Richards' structure. (May be alternating as well as uniform.))
I do not think it promising to try and lump the delay in the path of the reflected wave, only as your sketch suggests.

Could you give any graph to illustrate what you mean? A graph save a million word.

What structure change do you mean? I am confused

The structural change I'm referring to is two instances of "moving" a delay of $T/2$ from the top/incident wave to the bottom/reflected wave.

(Then again, in the meantime I've come across several images showing delays there, only.) Which reminds me: do you know about DSP@SE?

I don't know DSP@SE. Can you provide a link for those images?

"The structural change I'm referring to is two instances of "moving" a delay of T/2
from the top/incident wave to the bottom/reflected wave"
Could an image be provide here?

(A search engine pointed me to https://dokumen.pub/dsp-integrated-circuits-1stnbsped-0127345302-9780127345307-9780585470474.html.)

There is nothing in your link

(stackexchange.com lumps together the web address and the fullstop terminating my sentence: remove the trailing low-dot from the address.)

That's the book link. Isn't it? Still, there is no image for what you mean
